# CLR Stored Procedure thread exception

Tags: .net, sql-server, clr, clrstoredprocedure, threadabortexception

I have the follow code that works in an exe and even works on small xml files in the CLR but once they get larger than 10mb I get a thread abortion error. Is there something I need to configure in SQL Server?

```vb
Try

    sStream = HttpRequest.GetRequestStream()
    sStream.Write(baByteArray, 0, baByteArray.Length)
    sStream.Close()
    wrWebResponse = HttpRequest.GetResponse()
    sStream = wrWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim readStream As New StreamReader(sStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    strXmlResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd() ' Errors out here
    strXmlResponseDoc.LoadXml(strXmlResponse)
    wrWebResponse.Close()
    sStream.Close()
    readStream.Close()

Catch ex As Exception

    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.ToString())
    clsE.LogError(ex.ToString())

End Try
```

Error message:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
 at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
 at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
 at   System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.ClrLevelContext.CheckSqlAccessReturnCode(SqlAccessApiReturnCode eRc)
 at System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.ClrLevelContext.SendMessageToPipe(String message, SmiEventSink eventSink)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlPipe.Send(String message)
 at MacCLR.MacClass.RequestXml(String strXmlToSend)
 at MacCLR.StoredProcedures.ProcessShippingXML_1(String iOrderNumb, String iXmlFilePath, String iXmlFileName, SqlInt32& iResult, SqlString& iResult_String)
```

Comment: Yes. It's a CLR Stored Procedure in .NET

Comment: Cool.  I added a .NET language tag which should always be the primary tag on SO.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't download files from SQLCLR. Do it from an external .exe

Comment: +1 Remus. Somejerk, see the list of supported libraries for CLRs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx If you need a namespace that is not in the list, use an external .exe. Unsupported namespaces may cause memory leaks or security holes which can bring a production sql server to it's knees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting in a using block for each of the IDisposable interfaces I was still getting an error about  but it led me to realize that it is a 32 bit SQL Server installation and from what I read it handles CLR memory differently than 64-bit. Using the ;-g384 startup parameter at least bandaided the error until I can implement a more robust solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Every object you create that implements the `IDisposable` interface needs to be in a `Using` block. That ensures the object is cleaned up promptly, regardless of exceptions. That includes the two streams, the WebResponse, and the StreamReader.

This is especially critical for code that's running inside of the SQL Server process.

Comment: I'm going to put the code in a using block but It seems strange it works fine on ~1mb files.

Comment: It's not at all strange. You're eating up resources that won't be disposed of until a Garbage Collection cycle, if at all. The larger the resources, the more of a problem you'll have.